# B'racha on oat milk

Tags: blessing, food

> Oat milk is a popular dairy-free, vegan-friendly milk substitute. It's made by soaking and blending steel-cut or rolled oats with water and then straining them through cheesecloth to separate the milk from the oats. (from [Healthline](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/oat-milk))

What is the b'racha on oat milk? Would it be shehakol by analogy with milk and other beverages, or might it be mezonot because it is derived from grain?

Comment: In short IIRC, the algorithm is simple: 1. Is it how it's usually consumed (is oat made for the milk?)? Yes - same Brocho, no Sheakol 2. Does it retain the original qualities (form, texture)? Yes - same Brocho, no - Sheakol.

Comment: I have been struggling with this question for a while. It does not look like there is a consistent way of making oatmilk. Some websites suggest soaking and straining oats like shown above, in which case the bracha is most definitely Shehakol just like beer - see tosfos Brachos 39a. But if you look at the ingredients on SoDelicious brand oat milk ice cream, it lists oat flour, so obviously they have a different production method involving the actual oat flour. This might actually be mezonos similar to שתיתא עבה brought in Brachos 39a, although it would be much more complicated.

Comment: This all assumes "oats" are "שבלת שועל", @Silver. When you throw in all the Rishonim who thought otherwise then any Safek about thickness or whatever would likely tend to Shehakol anyway.

Comment: I think this would fall into the same discussion as orange juice, which is discussed in Tal. Brachot, I believe. There, it discusses the main purpose of the fruit. If it's for its juice then it would be *ha'etz*. As to why, in actuality, OJ is *shehakol* - I don't recall. Oats, assuming that they fall as *mezonot* as @DoubleAA mentions adds another layer of doubt. Regardless, it seems that oats are grown mainly to be used as flour, cereals, etc. I don't suspect that its main purpose is for oat "milk".

Answer (score 3):

There is no debate in the poskim, the bracha on oat milk is shehakol. See [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim Siman 208 Sif 6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.208.6?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) and Gemara Brachos 38A

(same for all 5 grain based drinks such as beer or soup with flour added where its still "drinkable" as long as no pieces are visible [if pieces are visible then subject to machlokes if both mezonos and shehakol or only mezonos)[regardless of the debate over juices , coffee and tea in the achronim, grain based drinks are shehakol according to all opionions. It doesnt have the special elevated status of regular mezonos when in drink form as it does not satiate like mezonos foods or because it is considered a shinui lgreyusa even on an item such as beer]

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!